# Flutter accessibility focus go back to top of the page after selecting an option in a dropdown/popup menu

Tags: flutter, accessibility

I noticed when I open a dropdown/menu popup in Flutter and then I select an option, the accessibility box goes back to the top of the page. I think it could be misleading for the user, since it was in the middle of the page before and then he have to go through all the views again.

I tried requesting focus in the ***onSelected()*** method of the popup, or moving the focus to the next view, but none of this worked. It's a stateful widget, but I don't think this could be the problem. Any solution to maintain the accessibility box on the dropdown after a new value is selected? Wrapping the entire widget with the Semantics widget didn't work either.

For reference, here the code:

```
Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
            color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color ?? Colors.white),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 21, bottom: 21),
        child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 48),
          itemBuilder: (context) {
            return dropdownOptions.map((String value) {
              return PopupMenuItem(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 18),
                value: value,
                child: Semantics(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 25,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        if (dropdownValue == value) ...[
                          const VerticalDivider(
                            endIndent: 0,
                            indent: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            thickness: 2,
                          ),
                        ],
                        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16)),
                        Text(
                          value,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                dropdownValue ?? dropdownOptions.first,
                style: const TextStyle(height: 1),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              SvgPicture.asset(
                IconsFI.dropdownArrow,
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                height: 18,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          onSelected: (v) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = v;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Edit: I just found [this issue on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40101). It's marked as closed but it seems like the issue is still there. I don't if anyone found a workaround during these years.

Comment: may can you add some example pictures, how it looks and how it should be looking

Comment: unfortunately I can't because it's a customer's app of a big company and I can't share screenshots. Basically the popup button is in the middle of the page, and the first element of the page is a custom toolbar. The focus goes to the back button of the toolbar after I select an item, which is the first view in the top left corner of the screen